# Should i release listeners?

Tags: android

I am interesting when I should release listeners and if it is necessary? Will a memory leak if I don't do it?

I know that need release something like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   currentUser.addOnUserUpdateListener(this);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    /* will be serious leak memory if don't do this */
    currentUser.removeOnUserUpdateListener(this);
}
```

But how about

```
setNavigationOnClickListener, 
setOnEditorActionListener
....
```

Will they do leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will they do leak?

In the above simple case, it shouldn't. Using Android framework listeners usually don't need special handling, unless specifically specified in the documentation. For the above methods, no special handling.

Usually memory leaks are caused when the Garbage Collector cannot collect the object references. Like holding a reference to a heavy object, like an `Activity` or `View` that can't be easily released. Or for inner classes that are not declared as `static` as they implicitly have a reference to the parent class.

Answer (score 3):

> Will they do leak?

difficult to say without seeing how are both handled. If you want to be sure, call them with `null` as parameter.